# Kalman Filter with measurement delays (Out of Sequence Measurement Problem)

Tags: kalman-filter

I have an understanding of how the Kalman Filter (as well as some of its nonlinear extensions like EKF and UKF) works as a linear estimator for a task such as tracking an object.

With real world systems, there can be some latency/lag when the measurement data arrives to be fused. If I have data that is delayed randomly (say I know the time the measurement is taken as well as the time when the measurement arrives at the filter), it is possible that some of the measurements arrive out of order (called the Out-of-sequence measurement problem). Some standard solutions that I know of include dropping such measurements that arrive afterwards. Another is creating a buffer of measurements and sorting them in the correct order after the buffer is filled, but if I have an exceedingly long delay between measurements a buffer is sometimes not feasible if I want a real time update with a short enough buffer.

What are some other solutions to this out-of-sequence measurement problem? I know there are some papers that propose modifying the Kalman gain when doing the measurement update step for a previous measurement, but it generally is for a nonlinear Kalman filter (i.e. http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/dossier/RESEARCH/2007cco-.pdf). I would like to know if there are other solutions to this issue that are not computationally expensive and help to provide more accuracy to the filter, rather than dropping those measurements.

Comment: I'm new to this field and doing some research into this exact issue. The paper you linked looks extremely helpful! It looks like the SPKF model can be reduced back down to a linear model, which would allow you to apply the results of this paper in a simplified manner.